# Estimating the resource usage breakdown of a project at initial proposal time?

Tags: estimation

How can one estimate the resource usage breakdown of a project at initial proposal time?

For example in fixed price project, say a ten-member team project with project duration 12 months

- 1 PM
- 1 Architect
- 1 PL
- 8 Developpers

Are there any standards (in terms of percentage of resources) available to estimate the team?

Comment: Um, `8 + 3 = 11`. How are you getting "ten-member team" from that?

Answer (score 1):

### Calculating a Person-Year

A twelve-month project is essential one person-year per resource. There are a number of ways to calculate a person-year, but in the US the typical baseline figure is 2,000 hours annually.

```
(40 hrs/week * 52 weeks) - 10 days paid time off
```

Calculations can vary. Some companies subtract holidays, sick days, vacation days, and paid time time (PTO) as separate line items from the annual total, while other companies use a different starting figure than 2,080 working hours per year. In other words, your mileage may vary.

### Your Estimated Labor in Man-Hours

Assuming you use the baseline figure of 2,000 man-hours per resource per year, you will have:

```
2,000 man-hours per resource * 11 people = 22,000 man-hours per year
```

One assumes they won't all have the same hourly rate or salary, but you could certainly average it out for a quick-and-dirty estimate, or provide a resource-by-resource breakdown if you need a more accurate figure. For example, if your 11-person team has an *average* salary of $80,000 per year, then you might estimate $880,000.00 for your annual labor budget, or round it up to $1M as a modest fudge factor.

### Breaking Down Utilization

I'm unaware of any way to get a finer-grained estimate of per-resource utilization unless you front-load the work of defining your work breakdown structure (WBS) and assigning resources to each work package. In other words, if you estimate you will only need 3 developers for Package A, but six developers for Package B, you can certainly create some pretty charts with that sort of information.

In my personal experience, though, it's all hogwash. [Parkinson's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law) is often generalized to:

> The demand upon a resource tends to expand to match the supply of the resource.

Meaning that if you have 11 people assigned to a project, it will take 11 people working full time to complete the project. Charts and plans to the contrary, you should pragmatically assume full resource utilization and around 60-80% productivity. Your mileage may vary, I suppose, but I wouldn't risk the success of a fixed-price contract on the assumption that your best-case estimates are the likeliest outcome.